# How to save intercepted request body to outside variable

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-intercept

how can I save request body to outside variable.
I want to do something like this:

```
let request;
  cy.intercept("POST", "/url**", ( req => {
    request = {...req.body};
    req.reply({
      body: response
    });
  }));

// use the "request" variable
// ...
```

and want to share this copied variable with other functions, but `cy.intercept` does not allow you to do this. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a wait to your code, since `cy.intercept()` is just a declarative event listener. Adding a wait for it's alias ensures that it has been triggered.

Also, since the code is async you will probably need to wrap and alias `request` to use it in other parts. Using the raw request variable might give you the empty value, depending on context.

Ideally you would do this in a `beforeEach()` I think. You probably also need to add the trigger for the POST call - is is a cy.visit()?

```js
let request;

cy.intercept("POST", "**/url/**", ( req => {
  request = {...req.body};
  req.reply({
    body: response
  })
})).as('myIntercept')

// Must cy.wait (not cy.get) the first occurrence
cy.wait('@myIntercept') 

cy.wrap(request).as('myRequest')

// use the "request" variable
cy.get('@myRequest').then(request => {...
```

or take request from the wait result

```js
cy.intercept("POST", "**/url/**").as('myIntercept')

// Must cy.wait (not cy.get) the first occurrence
cy.wait('@myIntercept').its('request')
  .then(request => {
    ...
  })

// 2nd time use get()
cy.get('@myIntercept').its('request')
  .then(request => {
    ...
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this option does not work for me, I've got an error: `CypressError: Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: myIntercept. No request ever occurred.` The test didn't even reach the site. The flow in the test was like this: `it("test", () => { mock (); cy.visit ("https://stackoverflow.com/");}) })`
where `mock()` is a function in separated module where I wrote code above

Comment: If you get that error, it means the `intercept` is not firing, which means the assignment to variable `request` cannot happen. You need to check the string `"/url**"` - are you able to share the actual url you want to catch?

Comment: Paolo, thank you for the reply! Unfortunately I can't share url because it's local environment. I will probably decide to abandon the idea of saving the request to a separate outside variable, since Cypress does not allow this to be done in a convenient way out of the box (for intercept option)

Comment: Ok, but in case you want to fix the intercept try pasting the full url into the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aliases for this.

```js
let somevalue;

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  it('Test case', () => {
    cy.intercept("POST", "/url**").as('urlReq')

    cy.get('@urlReq').then((urlReq) => {
      // urlReq.body will have the intercepted request body
      somevalue = urlReq.body.key
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Alapan, but I would like to achieve saving the request to a variable outside the scope of the arrow function. I need this to be passed between other functions or passed to another function as an argument. In my test framework, the mocks are in a separate module in the form of functions so that I can call them in tests, so I need to store the request outside of `then` scope.

Comment: Is there a specific key-value pair from the request body that you're trying to save and reuse?

Comment: ideally, I would like to save the entire request, but there are only three key-pairs in the current task, so I can save them in three separate variables

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now, `somevalue` will have a global scope. You can use it through the test and also pass this as a parameter to other functions.

Comment: well, propably I'm doing something wrong because I've got an error: Cannot read property 'body' of null 

`let request;`

`export function() {
  ...
  cy.intercept({method: "POST", path: "/url**"}, {
    body: response
  }).as("catchRequest");

  cy.get("catchRequest").then((req) => {
    request = req.body['key'];
  })
}`